# Typo3 External importer is not mapping extended news fields

Tags: sql, import, typo3, external

Using `cobwebch/external_import` and after extendig `tx_news_domain_model_news` with custom fields I try to map on import those. But the new created fields are not getting recognized by mapper.

my config which relays in `TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php` and looks as it follows

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['link_external']['external'] = [ 'news' => [ 'field' => 'tx_newsrundbrief_ext_link' ], ];
```

I'm using version 5.1

What I'm missing in this case?

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_?

Comment: Hi @jarlh the extension is a database migrator based on mysql

Comment: So you expect a SQL answer?

Comment: No I expect a Typo3 developer answer